# Angular one table with two paginators

Tags: angular, components, frontend, composition

I'm building an Angular GUI from components based on material lib:
https://material.angular.io/

I have a page with a table and a bottom paginator. I want to offer the same paging settings at the top of the page. But the table allows only one instance of the paginator:

```
get paginator (): MatPaginator | zero;
set paginator (paginator: MatPaginator | null);
private _paginator;
```

I found many solutions for two tables with own paginators on one page. But it is not this case.

So, is there a way to **connect 2 paginators into one table**?

Thanks, 
MB

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your main paginator:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="totalRecords" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50]"></mat-paginator>
```

You can add second paginator which properties are bound to the first paginator (this will ensure that that when first paginator changes the changes will be reflected to the second one) and hook up to it's (page) event to ensure that changes will be reflected on the first paginator (and by that, to the datasource as well):

```
<mat-paginator (page)="syncMainPaginator($event)" [pageSize]="paginator.pageSize" [pageIndex]="paginator.pageIndex"
  [length]="paginator.length" [pageSizeOptions]="paginator.pageSizeOptions"></mat-paginator>
```

In your .ts file you need to grab the first paginator (or grab the component by id if there are more paginators):

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator)
  paginator: MatPaginator;
```

And define the function to sync both paginators:

```
  syncMainPaginator(event: PageEvent) {
    this.paginator.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
    this.paginator.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.paginator.page.emit(event);
  }
```

Make sure that the main (first) paginator is attached to the MatTableDataSource.

Note: I'm using custom DataSource class, so this might need some tweaking, but should give you the proper idea of how you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. It works, but I have no clue if it is not a performance clog

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" #primaryPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageOptions"></mat-paginator>

<mat-paginator [pageSize]="primaryPaginator.pageSize"
               [length]="primaryPaginator.length"
               [pageIndex]="primaryPaginator.pageIndex"
               [showFirstLastButtons]="primaryPaginator.showFirstLastButtons"
               [pageSizeOptions]="primaryPaginator.pageSizeOptions"
               (page)="primaryPaginator.pageIndex=$event.pageIndex;primaryPaginator.pageSize=$event.pageSize;primaryPaginator.page.emit($event)"
```